# How to compare all rows of one dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have one dataframe like this:

```
Customer A B
[Boby    1 2]
[Alan    5 3]
[Tom     7 1]
```

*Attention: this is only a part of the dataframe for example (there are only a few thousand rows, dozens of columns).*

For each pair of customers, I need to find the sum of the squares of the differences between each row for A and B.

Boby-Alan calculation example:
((1-5) ^ 2 + (2-3) ^ 2) = 16 + 1 = 17

Boby-Tom ((1-7) ^ 2 + (2-1) ^ 2) = 36 + 1 = 37

Alan-Tom ((5-7) ^ 2 + (3-1) ^ 2) = 4 + 4 = 8

**Question 1**: How do I do such a calculation?

I tried searching, but there were examples with loops and I could not figure them out :(

**Question 2**: In what form should I store such a view?

I think in the form:

```
Сustomer1 Сustomer2 Sum
Boby       Alan      17
Boby       Tom       37
Alan       Tom        8
```

If question is unclear and need any explanations,please let me know in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

One Way:

Create all possible combinations:

```
from itertools import combinations
df1 = pd.DataFrame((combinations(df.Customer, 2)),
                   columns=['Customer1', 'Customer2'])
```

Evaluate the sum (Method 1):

```
df1['sum'] = df1.apply(lambda x: x.map(df.set_index('Customer').apply(np.array, 1))).apply(
    lambda x:  np.sum(np.square(x['Customer1'] - x['Customer2'])), 1)
```

Method 2:

```
map_dict = df.set_index('Customer').apply(np.array, 1).to_dict()
a = df1.applymap(lambda x: map_dict[x]).values
df1['sum'] = np.sum(np.vstack(np.square(a[:, 0] - a[:, 1])), 1)
```

OUTPUT:

```
  Customer1 Customer2  sum
0      Boby      Alan   17
1      Boby       Tom   37
2      Alan       Tom    8
```

Comment: Wonderfull! It works! Really great! Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Additional question: what should I do if my df like this: d = {'Customer': ['Boby', 'Alan', 'Tom'], 'A': [1, 5, 7], 'B': [2, 3, 1], 'Player': ['Hot', 'Cold', 'Warm']} and I need sum only A and B?